# What's the best way to convert String into [Character] in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to run a filter on a string. My first attempt failed as string is not automagically converted to Character[].

```
var s: String = "abc"
s.filter { $0 != "b" }
```

If I clumsily convert the String to Character[] with following code, it works as expected. But surely there has to be a neater way?

```
var cs:Character[] = []
for c in s {
    cs =  cs + [c]
}

cs = cs.filter { $0 != "b" }

println(cs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but try `Array(s)`.

Comment: @AlexGaynor that also works but you would need to then call reduce to get it back to a String (just as Maria's requires)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` conforms to the `CollectionType` protocol, so you can pass it directly to the function forms of `map` and `filter` without converting it at all:

```
let cs = filter(s) { $0 != "f" }
```

`cs` here is an `Array` of `Character`s. You can turn it into a `String` by using the `String(seq:)` initializer, which constructs a `String` from any `SequenceType` of `Character`s. (`SequenceType` is a protocol that all lists conform to; `for` loops use them, among many other things.)

```
let filteredString = String(seq: cs)
```

Of course, you can just as easily put those two things in one statement:

```
let filteredString = String(seq: filter(s) { $0 != "f" })
```

Or, if you want to make a convenience `filter` method like the one on `Array`, you can use an extension:

```
extension String {
    func filter(includeElement: Character -> Bool) -> String {
        return String(seq: Swift.filter(self, includeElement))
    }
}
```

(You write it "Swift.filter" so the compiler doesn't think you're trying to recursively call the `filter` method you're currently writing.)

As long as we're hiding how the filtering is performed, we might as well use a lazy `filter`, which should avoid constructing the temporary array at all:

```
extension String {
    func filter(includeElement: Character -> Bool) -> String {
        return String(seq: lazy(self).filter(includeElement))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built in way to do it, but you could write your own filter method for String:

```
extension String {
    func filter(f: (Character) -> Bool) -> String {
        var ret = ""
        for character in self {
            if (f(character)) {
                ret += character
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use an extension you could do this:

```
Array(s).filter({ $0 != "b" }).reduce("", combine: +)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
var chars = Character[]("abc")
```

I'm not 100% sure if the result is an array of `Character`s or not but works for my use case.

```
var str = "abc"

var chars = Character[](str)

var result = chars.map { char in "char is \(char)" }

result
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a char to string is using the backslash (), for example I have a function to reverse a string, like so.

```
var identityNumber:String = id
for char in identityNumber{
    reversedString = "\(char)" + reversedString
}
```